# Animate parent div when an input is focused

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make it so when someone clicks on the input box it rises to the top of the screen. I am able to make this work but I can't the other content within the parent div to move with it. Here is what I have:

```css
container{

} 
input#search-bar:focus{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #008ABF;
  transition: 0.35s ease;
  color: #008ABF;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="brandHeader">
    <h1>My Header</h1>
  </div>
  <form class="formHolder">
    <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```

What I want is My Header to also move up 10px at the same time as the search bar.

If you need any additional information that I forget to provide please ask and I will post it.

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS the way your HTML is structured right now. There is no way to select parents or previous siblings with CSS. You'd have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A Pure CSS Solution - Flexbox Order**

If you are able to restructure your html a little it's possible by changing the dom so `input` is 1st in the html but 2nd on screen. This method uses flexbox `order` to do so.

Here's an example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  order: 2;
}
.brandHeader {
  display: flex;
  order: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
input:focus + .brandHeader {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="container">
  <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search">
  <div class="brandHeader">
    <h1>My Header</h1>
  </div>
</form>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/djj01x6e/

If that would work for you let me know and I'll explain more about it.

---

**A 2nd Pure CSS Solution - flex-direction: column-reverse**

Pretty much the same as the first but no need to use `order: x;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
} 
input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
.brandHeader {
  display: flex;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
input:focus + .brandHeader {
 margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="container">
    <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="brandHeader">
      <h1>My Header</h1>
    </div>
</form>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/djj01x6e/1/

---

You can do a similar thing without flexbox using position: absolute to keep input 1st in dom but 2nd on screen but it too depends on your being able to change html structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle or addClass to `brandHeader` on `input:focus` with jQuery, then you can add the transition to both `h1` and `input`