# CSS: + selector not working when hover on child

Tags: css

I know this question is ask many time before but i didn't get the answers as i expected.... I am trying to hover on **.h4size** and effect on .**fsize** i use below css its not working...

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="div-square">
                               <a href="product.php" >
                            <i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x fsize"></i>
                          <h4 class="h4size">Saloon Product</h4>
                          </a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.h4size:hover .fsize {
   color: #c90000;
    text-shadow: 4px 6px 3px #202020;
}
```

**i also tried**

```
.div-square .fsize .h4size:hover + .div-square .fsize {
    color: #c90000;
    text-shadow: 4px 6px 3px #202020;
}
```

its also not working

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: This is not possible in any straightforward way.

Comment: See if either of these help.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39157544/3377049

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen i saw this code its also not working

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the html code but have it display the way you originally intended with `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column-reverse;`

Then use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) '`+`' to target the `<i>` tag from the `<h4>` tag.

```css
a { text-decoration: none; color: black; }
.reorder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
h4:hover + i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="div-square">
    <a class="reorder" href="product.php">
      <h4 class="h4size">Saloon Product</h4>
      <i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x fsize"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is using flexbox and `order`

Here's the original answer..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157544/3377049

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/9nvgvnxx/

More about flexbox at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Inderjeet I forgot to add the selector information but I think you had it figured out already.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here is solution :

https://jsfiddle.net/uvzqsggo/

Replace your HTML code with below: 
Just :  `<i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x fsize">Test</i>` this line :

I have add sample text Test but remove it(this is just for example)

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="div-square">
                               <a href="product.php" >

                          <h4 class="h4size">Saloon Product</h4>
                           <i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x fsize">Test</i>
                          </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wait let me try something other.

Comment: I think you should go to use jquery easy solution, if you don't want to change structure.

Comment: I found my answer without changing UI http://stackoverflow.com/a/43931181/6936747

Comment: That's great. But make sure its css3 property so it will not work in some browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="div-square">
     <a href="product.php"> 
        <h4 class="h4size"> <i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x fsize"></i> Saloon Product</h4>
     </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should i have to change my code if you have any answer regarding my current code please tell me.....i don't want it to change thanks for your suggestion....

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .fsize>.h4size:hover {
   color: #c90000;
    text-shadow: 4px 6px 3px #202020;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="div-square">
                               <a href="product.php" >
                            <i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x fsize">
                          <h4 class="h4size">Saloon Product</h4></i>
                          </a>
    </div>
```

> **This the easiest solution of your problem**