# Change css property of all the other elements li of a list (ul) while hovering an element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I really want to know if it's possible to change a property of all the other elements of a list while hovering one element of it.

Let's say that when I hover the "element 2", I want the others: "element 1", "element 3" and "element 4" css color property to change to "red" but not the hovered one.

Is it something possible just with css? is there a css selector for that actual feature?

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="element">element 1</li>
  <li class="element">element 2</li>
  <li class="element">element 3</li>
  <li class="element">element 4</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest and most elegant solution uses the `:not` *selector*:

```css
#list:hover .element:not(:hover) {color: red}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="element">element 1</li>
  <li class="element">element 2</li>
  <li class="element">element 3</li>
  <li class="element">element 4</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color of all `li` children by using the pseudo class `:hover` on the parent `ul`.

Then you just need to override the child currently hovered and set it back to the original color:

```css
ul:hover > li {
 color: red;
}

ul > li:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try by using parent selector

```
ul:hover li { color:red; }
ul li:hover { color:white;} // that should be default color
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't traverse up the DOM with CSS but for your example you can fake it like this..

```css
#list {
  background-color: gray;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#list:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.element:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li class="element">element 1</li>
    <li class="element">element 2</li>
    <li class="element">element 2</li>
    <li class="element">element 4</li>
</ul>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/u4w0z4sn/

Here's another way to [fake it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157544/3377049) (affect an element that is above it on the page, but not in the dom). It doesn't apply in this case but may be worth mentioning for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible with [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/:not) negation pseudo class.

```css
#list > .element:not(:hover) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li class="element">element 1</li>
    <li class="element">element 2</li>
    <li class="element">element 3</li>
    <li class="element">element 4</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="element">element 1</li>
    <li class="element">element 2</li>
    <li class="element">element 2</li>
    <li class="element">element 4</li>
<ul>
<style>
#list:hover{
    color:red;
}
 .element:hover {
    color: black; /* Replace black with Default color */
}
</style>
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to target all siblings that **follow** the element you're currently hovering over using the **[general sibling selector (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)**:

```css
ul > li:hover ~ li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="element">element 1</li>
  <li class="element">element 2</li>
  <li class="element">element 3</li>
  <li class="element">element 4</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use the **[adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** to target the sibling element that **immediately** follows the element you're currently hovering over:

```css
ul > li:hover + li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="element">element 1</li>
  <li class="element">element 2</li>
  <li class="element">element 3</li>
  <li class="element">element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately it is **not possible** to target **previous** siblings, so you cannot target `element 2` and highlight `element 1`, for example.

**However**, one solution might be to instead apply the hover to the `<ul>`, and simply 'reset' the hovered `<li>` to default with `color: inherit`:

```css
ul:hover > li {
  color: red;
}

ul:hover > li:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="element">element 1</li>
  <li class="element">element 2</li>
  <li class="element">element 3</li>
  <li class="element">element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Another solution (and perhaps the most elegant) would be to make use of the **[`:not` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)**:

```css
ul > li:not(:hover) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="element">element 1</li>
  <li class="element">element 2</li>
  <li class="element">element 3</li>
  <li class="element">element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Keep in mind that `:not` is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier.